# How can I check the windows compatibility mode of a running application

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, compatibility

I know, that I can set the windows compatibility mode for an application in its property page. But is there any way to see for a still running application, if it is running in compatibility mode or not. And can I see which special compatibility mode is used, because there are a lot of variants (and more than you can see in the property page).

This question concerns Windows 7 and Windows 10.

Answer (score -1):

Find the running program in the file explorer, and examine the compatibility settings. If they are not set, it's likely that it's not running in compatibility mode.

Comment: Unfortunatelely life is not as easy. What about child processes in any variation, Windows compatibility assistent, manifest... I want to be sure, which compatibility mode is set.

Comment: Windows compatibility assistant simply does what the user can do, so sets the properties. Child Processes will run with whatever they are configured to run with. You'll have to look at the properties of their executable.